# Using Tensorflow.Summary.Scalar. I get the Error Message: AttributeError: 'numpy.bool_' object has no attribute 'value'

Tags: python, tensorflow, anaconda, tensorboard

Thank you to anyone who could help me. I am very new to TensorFlow and I am trying to manually compute the Gradients. I also want to be able to visualise the evolution of key stats such as the mean of the Errors Squared. I am using the fetch_california_housing dataset. Unfortuntaly my program has a bug that I cannot pinpoint. The Error is computed but I fail in updating the summary tensor as it returns "false" and therefore won't be written in the File Writer. I would be really grateful if you could point me in the right direction.
First I import the data, normalise them, create a couple of functions to produce some mini batches, create some folders where should be copied the results

**Part 1**

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
from sklearn.datasets import fetch_california_housing
from sklearn import preprocessing

dataset=fetch_california_housing(as_frame=True)
x_data=dataset.data

r,c=x_data.shape
variables_plus_bias=np.c_[np.ones((r,1)),x_data]
variables_plus_bias=preprocessing.normalize(variables_plus_bias)

house_price=dataset.target.values.reshape((-1,1))

from random import sample

def load_batch(data_size_):
  list_=list(range(data_size_))
  np.random.shuffle(list_)
  return list_

def fetch_batch2(x,y,index,index_start,cp):
  x_=x[index[index_start:index_start+cp],:]
  y_=y[index[index_start:index_start+cp]]
  return x_,y_

learning_rate=0.01
n_epochs=5
batch_size=1000

tf.compat.v1.disable_eager_execution()
g=tf.Graph()

from datetime import datetime
now=datetime.utcnow().strftime("%m/%d/%Y, %H:%M:%S")
root_logdir="/Users/patrick/Documents/Python          Programming/Tensorflow/output/Tensor_flow_Gradient_descent"
logdir="{}/run-{}".format(root_logdir,now)
```

**Part 2**
**I create the graph**

```
with g.as_default():


    k1=tf.compat.v1.placeholder(dtype=tf.float32,name="k1")
    k=tf.compat.v1.placeholder(dtype=tf.float32,name="k")


    weight_tf=tf.Variable(tf.random.uniform([c+1,1],-1,1)
                   ,name="weight_tf")


    price_prediction=tf.linalg.matmul(k1,weight_tf)
    error_tf=tf.subtract(price_prediction,k)

    mse=tf.math.reduce_mean(tf.math.square(error_tf),name="mse")

    summary_variable=tf.summary.scalar("mse_summary",mse)


    optimizer = tf.compat.v1.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(learning_rate=learning_rate)
    training_op=optimizer.minimize(mse)



    init=tf.compat.v1.global_variables_initializer()

    saver=tf.compat.v1.train.Saver({"weights":weight_tf})
```

**Part 3**
**I launch a session**

```
with tf.compat.v1.Session(graph=g) as sess:

    file_writer=tf.compat.v1.summary.FileWriter(logdir,g)
    sess.run(init)

    for epoch in range(n_epochs):
        index=load_batch(r)
        if epoch % 100==0:
            save_path=saver.save(sess,"my_model.chkt")
        for batch in range(int(r/batch_size)):
            a,b=fetch_batch2(variables_plus_bias,
            house_price,index,batch*batch_size,batch_size)
            sess.run(training_op, feed_dict={k1:a,k:b})
            if batch % 10==0 and batch !=0:
            
                _,res_sum=sess.run([training_op,summary_variable],feed_dict={k1:a,k:b})          
                step=epoch*batch_size+batch
                file_writer.add_summary(summary=res_sum,global_step=step)
                file_writer.flush()
        
    file_writer.close()
    save_path=saver.save(sess,"/tmp/my_model_final.chkt")
```

**My error message is the following**

```
--->46 file_writer.add_summary(
        summary=res_sum,global_step=step)
47                 file_writer.flush()
48 

~/opt/anaconda3/envs/tf/lib/python3.10/site-  packages/tensorflow/python/summary/writer/writer.py in add_summary(self, summary, global_step)

121     # to save space - we just store the metadata on the   first value with a

122     # specific tag.

--> 123     for value in summary.value:
124       if not value.metadata:
125         continue

AttributeError: 'numpy.bool_' object has no attribute 'value'
```

Any help is more than welcome

I tried to manually compute all tensors and they pass test: Weights are updated. Predictions are calculated as well as the errors. But if I try update the tensor.summary then the bug appears. I have read I am not sure how many articles but I cannot see what I am doing wrong.